# Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Hi i am trying setup magento store everything working fine but if i click any products category its showing this error **Invalid backend model specified: catalog/product_attribute_backend_finishdate** please can any one help me on this